Getting an Empty Array When Parsing CSV File in ReactJS Upload Component
I'm working on a ReactJS project where I have an upload component that allows users to upload CSV files containing data about songs. Each row in the CSV file represents a song, with columns representing attributes like artist name, number of plays, duration, and song name.
I've implemented parsing logic in the upload component to extract this data from the CSV file and send it to the backend as a JSON object. However, when I log the songs array after parsing the CSV file, I get an empty array.
I've checked the CSV format, ensured that the parsing logic correctly splits each row into columns, and validated the data extracted from the CSV file. Despite this, I'm still encountering the issue.
I'm not sure what could be causing the songs array to be empty. Can someone please review my code and help me identify the issue?
Here's the relevant code snippet from my upload component:
import useAuth from './auth/useAuth';

const UploadPage = () => {
    const { getTokenHeader } = useAuth();
    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [uploadSuccess, setUploadSuccess] = useState(false);

    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        const uploadedFile = event.target.files[0];
        setFile(uploadedFile);
    };

    const handleDragOver = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleDrop = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const uploadedFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
        setFile(uploadedFile);
    };

    const handleUploadClick = async () => {
        if (!file) {
            console.error("No file selected");
            return;
        }

        const tokenHeader = getTokenHeader();
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);

        reader.onload = () => {
            const csvData = reader.result;
            const rows = csvData.split('\n');
            const songs = [];

            for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                const columns = rows[i].split(',');

                if (columns.length >= 5) {
                    const artistName = columns[0].trim();
                    const numberOfPlays = parseInt(columns[1].trim());
                    const duration = parseInt(columns[2].trim());
                    const songName = columns[4].trim();

                    if (artistName && !isNaN(numberOfPlays) && !isNaN(duration) && songName) {
                        songs.push({ artistName, numberOfPlays, duration, songName });
                    }
                    console.log(songs)
                }
            }


            const data = {
                fileName: file.name,
            };
            console.log(data)

            fetch('http://localhost:3000/radio/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    ...tokenHeader
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log('Upload successful');
                        setUploadSuccess(true);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            setUploadSuccess(false);
                        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
                    } else {
                        console.error('Upload failed');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error uploading:', error);
                });
        };

        reader.onerror = () => {
            console.error('Error reading the file');
        };
    };


    return (
        <div className="upload-container">
            {uploadSuccess && <div className="success-message">Upload successful!</div>}
            <div className="some-text">
                <h1>Upload your playlist here</h1>
            </div>
            <main className="upload-area" onDragOver={handleDragOver} onDrop={handleDrop}>
                <input
                    id="file-upload"
                    type="file"
                    accept=".xlsx, .xls, .csv"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                    style={{ display: 'none' }}
                />
                <label htmlFor="file-upload" className="drag-drop-box">
                    {file ? "Select another file" : "Drag and drop files here, or browse your computer"}
                </label>
            </main>
            {file && (
                <>
                    <div className="file-detail">{file.name}</div>
                    <button onClick={handleUploadClick} className="upload-button">Upload</button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default UploadPage;

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
